# Mapa que elimine valores automáticamente

Tags: java

Quisiera saber como hacer un Mapa (u otro objeto), en el que le meta objetos con un parámetro que sea: fecha expiración. He pensado en un HashMap con un Cron (@Scheduled), pero quisiera saber si existe alguna librería que ya tenga algo parecido y no tener que usar un Cron.

Ejemplo:

Elem 1: < key:"A", value:<..., expiredAt: 1578564268>>

Elem 2: < key:"B", value:<..., expiredAt: 1578564299>>

Dónde: 1578564268, 1578564299 son timestamps.

Encontré la clase PassiveExpiringMap[1] pero no me vale, ya que yo necesito que se eliminen individualmente los elementos cuando su fecha de espiración haya llegado y PassiveExpiringMap se eliminan todos los objetos tras un determinado tiempo.

[1] : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/PassiveExpiringMap.html

Comment: ¿Necesitas que se borre en el momento exacto de la expiración?, ¿o lo puedes mantener en memoria y borrarlo la siguiente vez que se haga get de esa clave y el momento actual haya superado la fecha de expiración?

Answer (score 2):

A menos que tengas problemas de memoria, podrías no borrar automáticamente y simplemente borrarlos cuando se intenten acceder y estén caducados. Por ejemplo podrías tener una clase así:

```
public class Cached<T> {

    private Instant when;
    private T data;

    public Cached(T item) {
        this.data=item;
        this.when = Instant.now();
    }
    public Instant getWhen() {
        return when;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Esta clase representa un elemento a guardar durante un tiempo. Se guarda el momento en el que se creó.

Y luego puedes crear una estructura así:

```
protected static final Duration CACHE_DURATION = Duration.ofMinutes(10);

private static final Map<Integer, Cached<Elem>> CACHE = new HashMap<>();

protected static Elem getElemFromCache(Integer id) {
    Cached<Elem> data = CACHE.get(id);
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Duration d = Duration.between(data.getWhen(), Instant.now());
    // Si ha caducado se borra en este momento y se devuelve NULL
    if (d.compareTo(CACHE_DURATION) > 0) {
        CACHE.remove(id);
        return null;
    }
    return data.getData();
}

protected static void removeElemFromCache(Integer id) {
    CACHE.remove(id);
}

protected static void addToCache(Elem u) {

    Cached<Elem> c = new Cached<>(u);
    if (CACHE.containsKey(u.getId())) {
        CACHE.remove(u.getId());
    }
    CACHE.put(u.getId(), c);
}

public static void clearCache() {
    CACHE.clear();
}
```